# Removing Title From Navigational Bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm working with Navigational Controller and I want to remove the title of the previous page that  is on the NavigationalBar like this:-

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113994/discussion-between-ei-captain-v2-0-and-kuldeep1007tanwar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**

You can also change it with this line of code:

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Title here"];
```

if you like to set back button title is blank...then just instead of Title here put there only space

**2**

or do like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
btn.title=@"";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btn;
```

**3**

Select navigation item from interface builder and change the Back Button string to what you'd like the back button to appear as. If you want it blank then just put a space.

**For title color**

**1**

```
    NSDictionary *titlecolor =@{
NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]
                               };
```

Assign the dictionary

```
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Your Title"];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titlecolor;
```

**2**

Suppose you want redColor

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

**For Background Color**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:107.0/256.0 green:145.0/256.0 blue:35.0/256.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

Comment: hey brother I'm also struggling with background color , I want to apply custom color so I use -    "self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:62.0f/255.0f green:165.0f/255.0f blue:254.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0] CGColor];" but it's not working any Idea @Suraj Sukale

Comment: and how am I suppose to make that button work suppose I Put @" < " but it will not work because it's just a string soo how can I go back? @Suraj Sukale

Comment: also color seems like gradient i want to apply plane color @Suraj Sukale

Answer (score 2):

You can remove navigation title from NavigationBar with this line of code:

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@" "];
```

Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set empty title for your navigation bar item button title
You can try this

```
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTitle:@" "];
```

OR

You can also assign a new button to your navigation bar item button

```
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = 
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " 
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                        target:nil 
                                        action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:myButton];
```

Comment: i found this working but it removed the back button any suggestion on that-""UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
btn.title=@"";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=btn;""

Comment: Here you have assigned a new button so, you need to make a method and call that method on the target of this(myButton) button.

Comment: how am I suppose to make that back button appear? @hites